# how to check a bluetooth device is connected

Tags: android, bluetooth

I need to develop an app to check whether my Arduino is connected to a bluetooth app.
I heard that for this I have to make a automatic bluetooth chat app, .i.e the bluetooth app should send a letter 'g' for every 1 minute, and arduino should check whether it gets the letter 'g' for every 1 min.

i am able to list paired devices in android studio, but I am unable to connect to the paired device. So can anyone help me to build an automatic bluetooth chat app?

Comment: Can you show what you´ve tried by posting for example your "list paired devices" code? You are asking very openly, however, this is a "we help you to fix your code" site, as opposed to a "how do I..." site.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
}
```

see [google documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)

btw, in order to check if the device support Bluetooth use this code (same doc.):

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
    // Device does not support Bluetooth
}
```

And, of course don't forget to ask for permission: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />`.

Comment: The question is how to check the Bluetooth device is connected.  But, your answer is checking bluetooth is supported or not.